# PHP CLI and Task Scheduler problem

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, php

I thought I had set up a successful schedule in Windows to run a PHP script. But all I got was an error which slaps only when run through the task scheduler.

**Here is how I run the task:**

I created a batch file *runCron.bat*:

```
start php.exe reportGenerator.php
```

and placed *reportGenerator.php* in the same folder as of the batch file.

When I manually execute the batch file, all is well. But when the same batch file is called by the task scheduler, PHP CLI throws the following error:

> Could not open input file:
>   reportGenerator.php

What would have been missed? I understand it's a path issue, but where exactly is the issue?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 start php.exe -f c:\full\path\to\reportGenerator.php
```

it probably looks for the script in the schedulers working directory, not in the bat file dir

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you. Since the batch file is calling php, I thought it should be taking its path as base. Now I understand that the first-caller always takes control of the path.